# jquery - enter key behaves differently depending on focus?

Tags: jquery, events, submit

Is there a way (using jQuery) to have the enter behave differently depending upon what textfield is currently active?

So, if I have:

```
<input type="text" name="different" value="something" />
<button id="somebutton">Go</button>

<textarea name="something">Some stuff</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="sendit" value="Send It" />
```

I'm trying to figure out how to run a function if the user is in the  and either hits enter or clicks , whereas if the user is in the textarea and hits enter, it'll submit the form...

Sorry, I'm not entirely certain of what to call this kind of behavior, which has made googling for it difficult...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input[name=different]").keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == '13')
{
  e.preventDefault();
}
});
$("textarea[name=something]").keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == '13')
{
  $("form").submit();
}
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mD3ek/)

Comment: Thank you for this... I did have to change keyup to keypress because otherwise there was still a postback, but definitely helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to attach a function to that textbox action and submit the form with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use IDs instead of names on your html elements.  Then do the following in javascript:

```
$("#different").keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //do something
    }
});

$("#something").keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Here is an implementation on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ByvjV/